# Write Ascii for Check Box when Converting to HTML

Tags: pandoc

I'm writing out to HTML but then copying the text and pasting into MS Teams. So, I would like the check boxes to be ASCII instead of HTML inputs.

I'm using pandoc version `2.10` on Windows.

This is what I think I should be doing. But it doesn't seem to work:

```
echo - [ ] Yep | pandoc --ascii -f MARKDOWN -t HTML
```

The above was done with the terminal `cmder`. I tried it with Powershell 7 like below and it still gives the incorrect result:

```
echo "- [ ] Yep" | pandoc --ascii -f MARKDOWN -t HTML
```

Returns:

```html
<ul class="task-list">
<li><input type="checkbox" disabled="" />
Yep</li>
</ul>
```

But I'm expecting:

```html
<ul class="task-list">
<li>☐ Yep</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution using a [Lua filter](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html):

```lua
-- file: unicode-checkbox.lua
function Str (s)
  if s.text == '☐' then
    return pandoc.RawInline('html', s.text)
  end
end
```

Use with command

```
echo "- [ ] Yep" | pandoc --lua-filter=unicode-checkbox.lua -f MARKDOWN -t HTML
```

Answer (score 2):

As you discovered, the following input renders a checkbox when outputting to HTML:

```
- [ ] Yep
```

This is due to pandoc's [task_list extension](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-task_lists), which you can turn off as follows:

```
pandoc -f markdown-task_lists
```

which will output:

```
<ul>
  <li>[ ] Yep</li>
</ul
```

However, what you seem to expect is the checkbox unicode char, you can do this e.g. with [generic raw attribute](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#generic-raw-attribute):

```
- `&#9744;`{=html} Yep
```

Answer (score 1):

After some trial and error, there are a few changes you need to make to the command:

```powershell
echo "\- &#9744 Yep" | pandoc -f markdown -t HTML | % {$_.replace("&amp;","&")}
```

1. `&#9744` is the HTML entity code for ☐
2. pandoc formats `&` as `&amp;` by default so you need to replace this in the output using powershell's replace `% {$_.replace("&amp;","&")}`.

This should give `<p>- &#9744 Yep</p>`, which is "- ☐ Yep" (without quotes) in HTML.

You can see the demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/Fermicide/4jsnoya3/1/

If you want to copy directly to the clipboard, you can pipe the output into `Set-Cipboard`:

```powershell
echo "\- &#9744 Yep" | pandoc -f markdown -t HTML | % {$_.replace("&amp;","&")} | Set-Clipboard
```